# Dynamodb poor read performance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, python-3.6, boto3

These days, I have tested Dynamodb performance and I have been disappointed at the performance.

I used `query` command on just partition-key without any filter condition. It means it just simply reads an index and return.

```
dynamodb.query(
    TableName='test-table',
    ReturnConsumedCapacity='TOTAL',
    KeyConditionExpression='tid = :tid',
    Limit=5000,
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':tid': {'N': '9999999'},
    }
)

---------- Part of Response ----------
{
    .
    .
    .
    "Count": 5000,
    "ScannedCount": 5000,
    "LastEvaluatedKey": {
        "tid": {
            "N": "9999999"
        },
        "uid": {
            "N": "985377"
        }
    },
    "ConsumedCapacity": {
        "TableName": "sam-push-test",
        "CapacityUnits": 110.5
    }
}
```

**It takes about 0.5 sec. It is tested in AWS Lambda(1024 memory) located in the same region as Dynamodb.**

I am curious that poor performance is a normal situation or there should be something I have missed.

Apparently, AWS is saying about Dynamodb delivers single-digit millisecond performance.

> Amazon DynamoDB is a key-value and document database that delivers single-digit millisecond performance at any scale.

In addition, `query-latency` metric in Dynamodb console shows 100-150ms on my test.

How is it measured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should expect single digit millisecond performance when reading or writing a single item. But when querying a page of 5000 items (as it seems to be in your case) it's normal to see ~100ms.

Of course, you should also make sure that the client is not too far away from the DynamoDB endpoint. A round trip around the world can easily add more than 100ms.

Comment: You mean my test result is abnormal, right?.  However, I run the test in AWS Lambda(1024M memory) located in the same region as Dynamodb. Even if I set Lambda memory as 3008M(maximum), reduction of response time is a bit small(0.5 -> 0.3 sec). Any checklist you can suggest about why it shows poor performance?

Comment: No, your test results appear normal. Instead of a Query, try a single GetItem request. That should return in < 10ms from Lambda in the same region. You are fetching 5000 items. It's normal that it takes around 100ms when fetching so many items.

Comment: Thank you for your answering!. I want to make clear again. Thus, 0.5 sec reponse time is all about round trip time and it is normal for getting a page(maybe 1Mbyte) even though Dynamodb query latency is just 100-150ms for a page?

Comment: The CloudWatch metrics should tell you the time it is taking DynamoDB to serve the requests. There's a separate graph for single GetItem and for Query. The difference between that latency and what you measure is likely coming from the client-side or from the round trip. If you're running this in Lambda from the same region, the round trip latency should only be about 1-2ms.

Comment: As my test result and your answering, the poor response time(0.5sec) is likely because of overhead to load data in client-side.